# Argument labels '(_:, heightForRowAt:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm still pretty new to coding so trying to get along with the concepts.

Here I'm trying to get the height of a UITableView that has dynamic cell heights.

Here is my part of the code.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    var tableViewHeight : CGFloat = 0

    for i in 0...((featureAndDynamicStatusDict["name"] as! NSMutableArray).count - 1)
    {
        tableViewHeight = tableViewHeight + tableView(self.dynamicDetailsTableView, heightForRowAt: NSIndexPath(row: i, section: 0))

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `NSIndexPath` in Swift. Use `IndexPath`.

Do not use `NSArray` in Swift. Use a Swift array.

Make sure your implementation of `heightForRow` has the proper signature of `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat` and not something slightly different.

Be sure to call `super.viewWillAppear`.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    var tableViewHeight : CGFloat = 0

    for i in 0..<((featureAndDynamicStatusDict["name"] as! [Any]).count)
    {
        tableViewHeight += tableView(self.dynamicDetailsTableView, heightForRowAt: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0))
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your class actually implement the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat` delegate method? And does it have that exact signature (and not something similar)?

Comment: yeah it turns out i was doing something wrong in heightForRowAt function.
The Error is gone now. Thanks. :)